# Reinitalizing Full Calendar Inside Function -- $(...).fullCalendar is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Using `FullCalendar` I am initializing on `document.ready`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        t = document.getElementById("calendar");
        var a, o, i, l = document.getElementById("calendar-title");
            n = (e = new Date).getMonth(),
            r = e.getFullYear(),
            s = <?php echo $shipments; ?>;
        (i = new FullCalendar.Calendar(t, {
            timeZone: "local",
            plugins: ["dayGrid", "interaction"],
            editable: !0,
            header: !1,
            height: "auto",
            events: s,
            datesRender: function() {
                var e = i.getDate();
                t.setAttribute("data-calendar-month", e.getMonth() + 1), l.innerText = i.view.title
            },
 . . . . . . . . . . .
 etc.
 </script>
```

And it works perfectly fine on page load.

Now I am trying to create a function that works within my FullCalendar instance to change the date.

```
<script>
    function changeDate(id, data) {
        date = getDate(data);
        console.log(date);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date );
    }
</script>
```

But within this function it is not detecting the existing FullCalendar instance that is already initialized, bringing back a console error of

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
```

What is the appropriate way to bind to the `FullCalendar` so I can create a function that interacts with my document loaded `FullCalendar`?

Comment: I really, really dislike your variable names. Because you've declared it inside a function `i` isn't available elsewhere. So you *could* make `i` global... but wouldn't anything that interacted with it, like, say, event handlers, *also* be declared in your DOM-ready function? Things would be much easier if you didn't scatter things everywhere, and this is one reason why. Rather than make a "raw" global, you could embed it in something unique (like an object).

Comment: Your calendar uses fullCalendar v4 which is no longer a jQuery plugin. Therefore you can't use jQuery syntax to refer to it. That's the reason for your error. Instead just use your calendar variable directly. See the v3-v4 upgrade guide for more details: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3

Comment: P.s. giving your variables single-letter names (apart from maybe trivial loop counters) is generally considered a bad practice. It makes the code harder to understand, and therefore harder to debug and harder to maintain in future. Always give your variables meaningful names. You'll thank me in 6 months time when you come to change something!

Comment: Thanks guys. Actually got this from a template and modifying (and learning!) as I go. Anyways, It works fine by declaring it as a global variable  outside of the document ready function --- `<script> var calendar $(document).ready(function() { calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar({ ...... }); </script>` -- and then accessible in my `<script> function changeDate(id, data) { date = getDate(data); calendar.gotoDate( date ); } </script>` -- Thanks @ADyson for pointing out I was using v3 syntax for `gotoDate` among the rest.  As mentioned -- not ideal, but works. One step at a time.